# 6 rows with 2 column to be shown as 2 rows and 4 column using php and mysql

Tags: php

I have 2 columns with 6 items

```
column A  column B
a         200
a         300
a         300
b         600
b         200
b         500
```

When I fetch the column in my html table i want it to be represented as follows:

```
column A column B column C column D
a        200      300      300 
b        600      200      500
```

using plain php and mysql

please can any 1 give me solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

1) `SELECT colA, colB FROM your_table`

2) Save data in an associative array;

```
   $colAdata=array();
   $colBdata=array();

   foreach ($results as $r) {
     if ($r["colA"]=="a")
          $colAdata[] = $r;
     else
          $colBdata[] = $r;
    }
```

3) Print based on the col they correspond to:

```
    echo "<table>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>A</td>";
    foreach ($colAdata as $r)
           echo "<td>".$r["colB"]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>B</td>";
    foreach ($colBdata as $r)
           echo "<td>".$r["colB"]."</td>";

    echo "</tr>";

    echo "</table>";
```

**update**

2)

```
   foreach ($results as $r) {
          $item = $r["colA"];

          if (!isset($coldata[$item])
              $coldata[ $item ] = $r;
    }
```

3)

```
    $possibilities=array_keys($coldata);

    foreach ($possibilities as $p) {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>$p</td>";
       foreach ($coldata[$p] as $r)
              echo "<td>".$r["colB"]."</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: Can you accomodate for the case when `colA` doesn't contain `a` and `b` only?

Comment: It would be a matter of having a `switch` instead of `if` in point 2) and a foreach in point 3). It is required?

Comment: what if you don't know the possible values in advance? You'd have to use an array of arrays then... (which needs some boilerplate to manipulate correctly)

Comment: Yes, would be a good idea I guess. We could have point 0) `SELECT DISTINCT colA FROM table`. Is it good like this or are there any other better way I cannot see now?

Comment: looks like a good starting point. If you really want to, you can suffice with just one query, though.

Comment: Well, you can also loop through results and feed an array with different possible values. I see the point, let's edit my answer.

Comment: @JanDvorak, you are right. I re-edited it to check if the value had already been set.